# Delete row from matrix given an id- Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

How can I delete a certain row from a matrix depending on the 1st column value?

For example: `A=[1 2 3;3 4 5;5 6 7]`
where the values of the first column represent the ids and I want to delete the row that has 5 as an id.
I already know that `A(3,:)=[]` deletes the third row, but what if I have the id and don't know the row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
id=5;
A(find(A(:,1)==id),:)=[]
A =

 1     2     3
 3     4     5
```

Note that, as mentioned by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar), thanks to logical indexing you can even omit the `find`:

```
A(3,:)
```

and

```
A(logical([0 0 1]),:)
```

are equivalent so

```
A(find(A(:,1)==id),:)=[]
```

and

```
A(A(:,1)==id,:)=[]
```

will give the same result.

Comment: You can omit that `find`as logical indexing takes care of it.

Comment: @Divakar you are the find is useless (except maybe for easier comprehension)

Comment: Well, if one is conversant with logical indexing, that would be easy to follow and also must be much faster, that's what I meant there.

Comment: I agree with you it's better without the `find` thanks for suggesting it. However I am not sure it makes a significant computational difference. I ran a few test and had similar runtimes. But then again, I still agree and would drop the `find` in my code!

Comment: Significant or not, at least I can guarantee it would be faster, as we are cutting off a function call of `find` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only element as `id`, then I would go with [@yoh.lej's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150186/3293881). But, if you happen to have an array of elements as `id`, you can use one of the approaches listed next.

**Approach # 1 (With [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html))**

```
A(ismember(A(:,1),ids),:) = [];
```

**Approach # 2 (With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html))**

```
A(any(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),ids(:)'),2),:) = [];
```

---

If the first column of `A` has unique `ids`, then you have two more approaches to play with.

**Approach # 3 (With [`intersect`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html))**

```
[~,remove_rowid] = intersect(A(:,1),ids);
A(remove_rowid,:) = [];
```

**Approach # 4 (With [`setdiff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html))**

```
[~,select_rowid] = setdiff(A(:,1),ids,'stable');
A = A(select_rowid,:);
```