# Delete Rows from matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, rows

I have a vector X (786432*1) and another T(786432*1).

I want to delete rows from X which have value 2 and I want to delete  the same(corresponding)rows of T -(for example delete X(1,1) and T(1,1))
no important the T values. very confusing with loop (index)

```
> [r c]=find(X==2);
```

How do I find same r and c in vector T?

How do I implement this in Matlab? Please any one can help!

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150143/delete-row-from-matrix-given-an-id-matlab

Answer (score 0):

You got how to find indices to remove:

```
idxs = find(X==2);
```

you can remove element at indices with:

```
X(idxs) = [];
T(idxs) = [];
```

Example:

```
>> X=randi(10,1,7);
>> T=randi(10,1,7);
>> X

X =

    10     3     2     2     1     5     5

>> T

T =

     6     9     3     4     2    10     7

>> idxs = find(X==2)

idxs =

     3     4

>> X(idxs)=[]

X =

    10     3     1     5     5

>> T(idxs)=[]

T =

     6     9     2    10     7

>>
```

Comment: You should explain your solution, the OP might not understand if you solely paste code.

Comment: You're welcome. If you appreciate and it has solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted.